# Reference request: review paper / overview of chemical oscillators

Tags: kinetics, reference-request

I know about the [Belousov-Zhabotinskii reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction) as an example of "chemical oscillator", e.g. a reaction that can produce repeating patterns over time as it exhausts its reagents. I also know about the [Briggs-Rauscher reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briggs%E2%80%93Rauscher_reaction) but I wonder how many such chemical oscillators are possible? Can somebody provide me with a good review paper and/or book reference written specifically to survey the range of all possible chemical oscillator systems?

To note, I know there are a lot of people outside of chemistry (particularly people interested in chaos theory and non-equilibrium thermodynamics) who do detailed research on modeling the detailed behavior of such oscillating systems, and I've found several such papers/reviews. But, what I'm looking for is a resource focusing on the *chemical properties* of oscillator systems, not the mathematics or dynamics modeling.

Comment: Even among non-biochemical oscillators there can be countless number of them.

Comment: @Mithoron , then why don't you give us some of these "countless numbers"? How about actually writing a descent reply and explaining some molecules who can be possible candidates to participate in chemical oscillators and the mechanisms of the reactions that can drive such oscillators. Providing some references would be nice, too. (Preferably some good review papers explaining how can we make an oscillator from reactions A, B, C, and so on and how would they work.) That will do the job!

Comment: https://books.google.pl/books?id=ci4MNrwSlo4C&pg=PA81&hl=pl&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Ever biological feedback system is technically an oscillator...

Comment: @Milthoron thanks for the link. I look it up but the whole book wasn't available on google books so I can't form an informed opinion about it, but from what I saw it's primarily "theoretic" work on the physics and mathematics of such reactions and mentions too few actual examples.

Comment: How is my question "too broad"? What precisely do you mean by "too broad"? I'm asking to tell me how many actual chemical oscillators have been done in real-world experiments (not "technically" or "potentially" or "theoretically") besides the 2 reactions I mentioned above. I want to know who has worked on different ways of creating oscillators and what reactions they had used. What is so "too broad" about this question?